# SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Error

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

Not sure where that is getting from.
I have included the actual error here:

```
Oct 29, 2014 4:30:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.warn(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Oct 29, 2014 4:30:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
Oct 29, 2014 4:30:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8184"]
```

Any help work be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve your issue, change the tiles dependency to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

and add the new dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Usually the dependency issue are easy to resolve by using `dependency:tree`, however, here the trick was that jcl-over-slf4j was including slf4j-api in a transitive dependency but without an explicit version. Maven dependency mediation has resolved the slf4j-api version to 1.7.7, so there was no obvious version conflict. Still you've ended up with a wrong jcl-over-slf4j version. That's why the exclude is on that dependency

Comment: With that change, now what I am having is `javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'` error. The tiles configuration looks good and pretty sure that's how it has to configure.

Comment: its a seperate issue for a separate post maybe, what I've posted should resolve only your dependency issue

Comment: That fixed the problem with the dependency. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem, the error in Jboss Deployment was:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 2017-09-18 19:15:20,350 [] priority=ERROR app_name= thread=HDScanner location=[XXX] line=3470 Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.warn(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:199)
```

In my case, the issue was with slf4j version mismatch , due to the new dependency i addded to the project.

So adding exclusions to the new dependency, resolved the issue.

```
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                   <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```